# How to properly insert an object into a List in Java?

Tags: java, list, insert

In this code, are there any differences between these two ways to insert an element into a list in Java?  If so, what are they? And what way should I use when inserting an element into a list?

```
List<MyClass>myList=new ArrayList<MyClass>();

myList.add(new MyClass());

MyClass foo=new MyClass();
myList.add(foo);
```

I'm a beginner in Java. I'm really sorry if you find this question obvious or non-sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference. You should do what you find the most readable. The second one is necessary when you need to do something with the object in addition to adding it to the list.

Note that Java is case-sensitive, and that classes conventionally start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

There's not any difference to the list.

The only difference is that in the second version, the following code has a reference to the added object, so you can do something with it (eg pass it to some other code or call methods on the object etc).

Answer (score 0):

The difference I find is related to garbage collection. If you are considering that you are not going to assign the object to any other variable,
Using the first one, if you remove the object from the list it becomes eligible for gc. In the second one the object will not be eligible for gc as long as either foo keeps the reference to the object or its available in the list.